# How to get same values when doing multipliation in php and jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have created currency conversion calculation using PHP and JQUERY. I have done same calculation both languages but I got different values. What I am doing wrong, Below is my code given.

**PHP**

```
$total = (double) $input * (double) $rate;
return number_format((double) $total, 2);
```

**Jquery**

```
total =  parseFloat(input) * parseFloat(rate);
return  total.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: What do you get in each case?

Comment: update your question show a  data sample and  the actula result

Comment: Please provide input data and what output you get in both cases

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nqz3baa0/  and https://eval.in/872553 gives same result

Comment: If your values have a certain degree of precision (i.e. there are a certain number of decimal places), then you're going to run into an issue where floating point numbers or "floats" (32-bit) are going to have slightly different values than double-precision floating point numbers or "doubles" (64-bit). I would encourage you to review the precision of your inputs and see if this might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

check out below code. works fine.both languages give same values.

```
<?php
$total = 14.23* 7.25;

echo number_format((double) $total, 2);
?>
```

103.17

```
<input type="text" id="number1">
<input type="text" id="number2">
<button id="click">Click me</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#click').click(function(){
total =  $('#number1').val()  * $('#number2').val();
alert(total.toFixed(2));
});
</script>
```

103.17